# Saving program working data

Tags: c#

When the program runs, the intermediate data must save in the user's computer.

Now I use .txt files, encoding with AES.

But file/code user can break, delete....

Maybe is better decision?

Comment: Are you asking how you can save data and ensure that no one messes with it?

Comment: Larsenal>Yes, I wrote about it

Answer (score 1):

To protect user's data against other users use [Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx), and C# has easy to use classes to facilitate its use: [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx), and there are examples on MSDN how to write protecetd data to a file, see [How to: Use Data Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741.aspx).

If you are asking how to protect data so that the very user of the program cannot decrypt it, that is **impossible** and all claims to the contrary are snake oil. You can make it *hard* to decrypt, but you'll never make it impossible. If you cannot send data to the user, then keep it on the server and make all interactions with the data through a remote API (sockets, REST, queueing, whatever).

Comment: void encrypt(ref string s){ s = ""; } // no way to decrypt

Comment: Remus Rusanu>Thank you for helping. I'm now using AES (RijndaelManaged) - so data encrypt.
But for example encrypted data looks like this:
"wdewqeqwe";
User open file, and change to this:
"wdewqeqwe123", and I've never not decode the file, because code is corrupt.
I hope you understand, my problem.